# How to reset a variable in tensorflow?

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, initializer

I want to execute a graph, change the value of a single variable, and then execute the graph again with the change absorbed by any downstream variables. As an example,

```py
A = tf.distributions.Normal(0.0, 1.0)
B = tf.distributions.Normal(0.0, 1.0)

a = A.get_variable(name="a", initializer=A.sample)
b = B.get_variable(name="b", initializer=B.sample)

C = tf.distributions.Normal(a + b, 1.0)

c = C.get_variable(name="c", initializer=C.sample)
```

So, if I run this graph,

```py
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run([a, b, c])
```

I get a set of values for a, b, and c. Then, say, I want to re-initialize b,

```py
    session.run(b.initializer)
    session.run([a, b, c])
```

This will re-initialize the value of b but that change is not propagated to c. Since b has changed, and c depends on b (through C), I want c to be re-initialized.

Is this possible in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

`c` does not depend on `b`, its initializer does. In fact, variables in tensorflow can't depend on other variables. After you re-initialize `b`, the value of `c` doesn't change. But if you run the `c` initializer again, it will pick up the new value. So simply do:

```
session.run(b.initializer)
session.run(c.initializer)
```

Comment: Why can't variables depend on other variables?

Comment: Nope. They can be changed independently, that's why they are *variables*